# Reverse geocoding what my opposite position

Tags: geocoding, reverse

What is my opposite position if my lat is 
35.3426120
Long 119.0191580
I have not been able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts to understand here:

[Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding): Which is determining a readable location (eg. Street name) based on the latitude and longitude. In your case somewhere in China

[Opposite Position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes): (aka Antipodes) Is best understood that if you were to dig a straight tunnel through the center of the earth from your current position, where will you end up?

Right so given these two things your answer in this case just west of Buenos Aires.

There are many ways to calculate this with different types of efficiency. You can start by looking at "Rotating Calipers".